# How to add same entity to soap array php

Tags: php, soap

after lot of neverending nights I can connect to external SOAP server with my client, bud I need to send there some array.
How have I construct that array to make something like this?

```
<ns0:InformaceBloky>
    <ns0:Informace>
        <ns0:Typ>NA010001</ns0:Typ>
        <ns0:Poradi>1</ns0:Poradi>
        <ns0:Popis>Popis_1</ns0:Popis>
    </ns0:Informace>
    <ns0:Informace>
        <ns0:Typ>NA010002</ns0:Typ>
        <ns0:Poradi>2</ns0:Poradi>
        <ns0:Popis>Popis_2</ns0:Popis>
    </ns0:Informace>
    <ns0:Informace>
        <ns0:Typ>NA010003</ns0:Typ>
        <ns0:Poradi>3</ns0:Poradi>
        <ns0:Popis>Popis_3</ns0:Popis>
    </ns0:Informace>
</ns0:InformaceBloky>
```

Part of PHP script:

```
    foreach ($zsBody as $zsBody_item_k => $zsBody_item_v) {
        $informaceBlok[$zsBody_item_k]['Informace'] = array(
            'Typ' => "NA01000$zsBody_item_k",
            'Poradi' => $zsBody_item_k,
            'Popis' => "<![CDATA[" . json_encode($zsBody_item_v) . "]]>"
        );
    }

    $data_aerg = array('InformaceBloky' => $informaceBlok);
```

Any ideas, pls, how to create that array?

Comment: Wrap the `array(...)` in another array.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `'Informace'` key at each iteration of `foreach`, instead initialize it as an array and append to it:

```
$informaceBlok[$zsBody_item_k]['Informace'] = array(); // initialize
foreach ($zsBody as $zsBody_item_k => $zsBody_item_v) {
    $informaceBlok[$zsBody_item_k]['Informace'][] = array( // append using []
        'Typ' => "NA01000$zsBody_item_k",
        'Poradi' => $zsBody_item_k,
        'Popis' => "<![CDATA[" . json_encode($zsBody_item_v) . "]]>"
    );
}
```